# Words for organizing paragraphs

Tags: word-choice, writing

When making a presentation or writing a essay, I often use words such as "First,...Second,...Third,...Finally,..." .

Could you tell me better words to paragraph sentences?

Comment: You may find https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Writing_Better_University_Essays/Main_part#Useful_Phrases useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a more prose like approach:

To start off...

Then..

After that..

Next..

Continuing on..

Later..

In the end..

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to be more formal you could use

> Firstly, secondly, thirdly,... finally.

which I use regardless of formality.

Since you seem to want to enumerate your paragraphs, you might use

> In the first case, ...
>   In the second case, ...
>   In the third case, ... 
>   Finally, ...